# Split conjunction goal into subgoals

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Consider the following toy exercise:

```
Theorem swap_id: forall (m n : nat), m = n -> (m, n) = (n, m).
Proof.
  intros m n H.
```

At this point I have the following:

```
1 subgoal
m, n : nat
H : m = n
______________________________________(1/1)
(m, n) = (n, m)
```

I would like to split the goal into two subgoals, `m = n` and `n = m`. Is there a tactic which does that?

Comment: Is it just for fun or there is some deep reason for splitting the goal?

Comment: No deep reason, I'm just trying to learn basic Coq idioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve using the [`f_equal`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic169) tactic:

```
Theorem test: forall (m n : nat), m = n -> (m, n) = (n, m).
Proof.
  intros m n H. f_equal.
```

With state:

```
2 subgoals
m, n : nat
H : m = n
______________________________________(1/2)
m = n
______________________________________(2/2)
n = m
```

Comment: A comment about the reason `f_equal` works: if we unfold some notations, we'll get from the goal `(m, n) = (n, m)` to `pair m n = pair n m`, where `pair` is the only constructor of the `prod` datatype. At this point it should be obvious why `f_equal` splits the goal into two subgoals.